# Eliminating Short Rows with read_table() using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

It seems as though the `error_bad_lines` and `warn_bad_lines` arguments are only for rows that contain too many columns, not too few columns. Is there a simple way to eliminate all short columns in a dataframe, preferably on reading it in?

For example, the following works great, however every now and then there is a one column row containing text rather than a timestamp. This prevents the conversion of the dataframe to the desired datetime index format.

```
data = pd.read_table(filepath, sep='\t', parse_dates=True, index_col='Date/Time', error_bad_lines=True)
```

The dataframe then resembles the image below:
[image]

I could iterate through the rows using `df.iterrows()` and weed out the bad rows, but I feel like there must be a better/faster/sexier way seeing as pandas is awesome.

Thoughts/ideas?

Feb 27, 2014:
As of now, I am accomplishing this using the following strategy:

1. Define function to return `True` if the index is a valid timestamp
2. Create a temporary column in the df that contains the index
3. Apply custom function to the temporary column
4. Keep only columns whose `temp` column are `True`

Looks something like this:

```
def valid_row(ind):
    return True if (type(pd.to_datetime(ind)) is pd.tslib.Timestamp) else False

data = pd.read_table(runDir + "VapsTest_20130429.txt", sep='\t', parse_dates=True, index_col='Date/Time', error_bad_lines=True, keep_default_na=False)

data['temp'] = data.index
data['temp'] = data['temp'].apply(valid_row)
data = data[data['temp'] == True]

data.index = pd.to_datetime(data.index)
```

This process gets the job done and leaves me with a clean, dataframe with datetime index. There absolutely has to be a better way, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can use those options referred to on the official documentation :

*error_bad_lines*: Lines with too many fields (e.g. a csv line with too many commas) will by default cause an exception to be raised.

*keep_default_na* : bool, default True , If na_values are specified and keep_default_na is False the default NaN values are overridden, otherwise they’re appended to.

and you can fix this problem with :

```
data = pd.read_table(filepath, sep='\t', parse_dates=True, index_col='Date/Time', error_bad_lines=False,keep_default_na=False)
```

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts. That seems to drop the rows with NaN as the index (good) although the row seems to still exist (just empty); I'm not sure if that will be a problem in the future. The main problem still exists, though. As seen above, some rows have text in the index, I need to get rid of those! I could just iterate through each row, try converting to a timestamp and delete if it fails, but that seems unnecessary.